# Google Maps - Multiple Markers via URL only

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

If I want to open a browser to Google Maps to center and show a single marker, I do it with a URL like this:

https://www.google.com/maps/place//@33.91729,-106.85761,10z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0

But, I have 5-10 lat/long pairs that I want to show on that same map. How can I show multiple lat/long markers all specified only in a URL?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, it is possible without directions. just add at the end: //@ . example:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/33.93729,-106.85761/33.91629,-106.866761/33.98729,-106.85861//@34.0593359,-106.7131944,11z
```

Comment: so why we need google api since routes and markers done using url are fully free. Am i right?

Answer (score 32):

There is an up-to-date article (updated: May 18 2017) about [easily linking](https://gearside.com/easily-link-to-locations-and-directions-using-the-new-google-maps/) to locations and directions using the New Google Maps.

You could use the directions service and form a url [as such](https://www.google.com/maps/dir//33.93729,-106.85761/33.91629,-106.866761/33.98729,-106.85861):

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/33.93729,-106.85761/33.91629,-106.866761/33.98729,-106.85861
```

Use double slash "//" between markers to leave a position empty e.g. to set a custom start point.

**Update**

There is another excellent article [here](https://moz.com/blog/new-google-maps-url-parameters)

Comment: But is it possible without directions... just the markers?

Comment: @LaurensKoppenol Yes, both articles have examples depending on what you want to achieve. The [moz.com article](https://moz.com/blog/new-google-maps-url-parameters) is more relevant if you want to place multiple markers on a map.

Comment: @raratiru Do you know a way to create circular area markers instead of default marker? [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51059535/google-maps-url-how-to-define-circular-marker)

Comment: This solution only seems to work for max. 3 locations. I'm looking to get directions between 50+ locations.

Comment: @Charlie I believe, if you ask Google, they will answer that everything is possible, depending on your pocket size! I mean, it is better to keep a low profile and probably separate those 50+ locations in pairs or triplets. Google limits are very tight in all aspects, this should not make an exception.

Comment: @raratiru they most certainly will! However, we're aiming for free solutions. Our project uses a function to generate routes based on air quality. Once a route is selected, I wanted to pass the route to Google Maps for directions. Do you know of any open-source alternatives?

Comment: @Charlie Wow, this sounds like an amazing project and idea! It is better to open a new question in https://gis.stackexchange.com/, it is possible to find there people who have more experience in this field.

Comment: Great, thanks! I believe the approach outlined in the answer will work if the URL is opened on mobile devices with the Google Maps app installed, but I have yet to try this. I'm currently testing on desktop and emulator without Maps. Directions is not necessary for an MVP, so I think we'll come back to this one later.

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to add that Yandex.Maps does offer [this feature](https://yandex.com/dev/yandex-apps-launch/maps/doc/concepts/yandexmaps-web.html#yandexmaps-web__section_b3b_cst_ngb) without an api key. The syntax is pretty simple: `https://yandex.ru/maps/?ll=[center longitude],[center latitude]&pt=[longitude1],[latitude1]~[longitude2],[latitude2]&z=[zoom level]&l=map`

Eg:

```
https://yandex.ru/maps/?ll=30.310182,59.951059&pt=30.335429,59.944869~30.34127,59.89173&z=12&l=map
```