# How to create an Google Maps URL with multiple Markers by Android API?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I've create an Android App to show some locations by GPS on a google map in the android application. Now i add an share button that should send an URL (google Maps) to someone by a plattform like WhatsApp, Telegram or so. I read some posts and blogs, but I can not find a solution.

Is it possible to create a goggle Maps Url by Android?

Answer (score 1):

As far as my knowledge is concerned I don't think there is any straight forward way to query multiple locations using google maps url. Either you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39311940/3602767) workaround or you can use [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/) to get your desired map as an static image and then share it on other apps like WhatsApp, Telegram etc. Static Maps API support multiple markers, polylines and much more.

Comment: Thank you for your answert, i've also seen both methodes, and I am quite unhappy about this fact. I'm asthonished, that there is no other was.