# Google map url with several marker

Tags: dictionary, url

I want to display several markers (later i want different circle) in Google map.
I want to generate just one link without API key if possible ?

My url example:

https://www.google.com/maps?q=[FORT DE FRANCE,97200]+[DUCOS,97224]+[COUSAIX,87270]+[REMIRE MONTJOLY,97354]+[LE LAMENTIN,97232]

but several points are not displayed ! 
Please how to do with this just with params ? 
Tanks a lot !

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35400664/google-maps-multiple-markers-via-url-only

Comment: yes, but it seems to me that it's a route. I want just markers. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible for multiple points on the URL. It seems what you need is [Google maps place marks](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#placemarks). If your data is static then you can [manually create the points on a google map](https://www.create.net/support/how-to-pin-point-multiple-locations-on-google-maps) and embed that link instead.

Comment: Yes it's not possible. So I use google API in JS. Tanks